# DocumentDb: Get the first document

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Is there an effective way of getting the first document from a query? Typically this would be using `FirstOrDefault()` with LINQ collects or a `TOP` in SQL.

Say the collection looks something like this:

```
{
    name: "John",
    position: 3
},
{
    name: "Mary",
    position: 1
},
{
    name: "Peter",
    position: 2
}
```

I need to retrieve only the single document with the highest value position.  I.e. the "Mary" document in this case.

Using the C# SDK, I would have to perform something like this:

```
Client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(Collection.DocumentsLink)
    .Where(somethingOtherCriteria);
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Position)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .FirstOrDefault());
```

This will retrieve ALL the documents in the collection (after applying the relevant filter) and then fetching the first from the list. This could still bring in thousands of irrelevant documents over the wire.

Is it not possible to execute `FirstOrDefault()` on the server?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to set the max response size to 1, and grab only the first page from the query iterator:

```cs
var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Family>(collectionLink, "SELECT * FROM myCollection", new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 1 }).AsDocumentQuery();
var feedResponse = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<Family>();
```

Comment: I hate to say it, but this is not correct. And I don't blame you for thinking it is, because I thought the same thing until I discovered, to my great chagrin, that it isn't. ExecuteNextAsync() filters the *page* by the query, not the result set.

Coincidentally, your code above will work because there's no WHERE clause. If your query includes a WHERE clause that excludes all of the first page (or in this case, the single result, since you're using a page size of 1) you will fail to return a result even if one exists.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/6771773-add-support-for-single-entity-retrieval-instead-of

```
Client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(Collection.DocumentsLink)
    .Where(somethingOtherCriteria);
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Position)
    .Take(1)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: This link no longer works , could you try to find an alternative source?

Answer (score 1):

You're close. Skip the AsEnumerable() and do this:

```
var query = Client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(Collection.DocumentsLink)
    .Where(somethingOtherCriteria);
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Position)
    .AsDocumentQuery();

while (query.HasMoreResults)
    foreach (var document in await q.ExecuteNextAsync<T>(cancellationToken))
        return document;
```

If you do it this way, you won't actually return any results but the one you want. The catch is, you do have to run ExecuteNextAsync() against every page of results until you get the page with your desired result -- but the other results won't come over the wire and won't get deserialized into a C# reference type.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for Take(), that's the Linq function that maps to TOP in the query. So you want something like

```
        var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<MyType>(collectionAddress)
            .Where(x => x.Value == myValue)
            .Take(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Cosmos DB .NET SDK Version ≥ 3**

You can use `GetItemLinqQueryable` for getting last item based on specific property like this:

```cs
var linqQuery = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<YourModel>(
     requestOptions: new QueryRequestOptions { MaxItemCount = 1 })
    .Where(someConditions).OrderByDescending(x => x.Postition);

using (FeedIterator<YourModel> feedIterator = linqQuery.ToFeedIterator())
{

    while (feedIterator.HasMoreResults)
    {
        var entity = await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync();

        foreach (var item in entity)
        {
            // handle item
        }
    }
}
```